# Cypher relating many nodes to one node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, agens-graph

Say I have all these objects in a graph:

```
5ffcedc70cc70
5ffd73259ad18
5ffd7394311bf
5ffd740fd836c
5ffd74b7001fe
5ffd746b3f457
5ffd74fc7d21d
5ffd75428691b
5ffd75f0509e0
5ffd7586a2916
5ffd789434539
5ffd78e65bae8
5ffd794fcb91a
```

And I want to relate them to a single node:

```
David
```

Singularly I'd:

```
MATCH (a:Object),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name = '5ffdbb309d9a6' AND b.name = 'David'
CREATE (a)-[r:CREATEDBY]->(b);
```

Is there anyway to loop through a list of objects so I can say `(Object)-[CREATEDBY]->(David)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a simple IN clause,
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#where-in-operator

```
MATCH (a:Object),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name IN ['5ffdbb309d9a6', '5ffd73259ad18' ...] AND b.name = 'David'
CREATE (a)-[r:CREATEDBY]->(b);
```

or am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks, new to cypher, coming from sql, graph databases seem so much simpler yet so much more powerful! (I know not applicable in every case)